# UDP between A and B only works if B sends packet first

Tags: linux, routing, port-forwarding, tcpip, udp

I have two separate linux computers, A and B, that need to communicate via UDP on port 3000. They are each behind a different router, and I have port forwarding rules set up on each router.

For some reason, the only way B is able to receive UDP packets from A is if B sends a packet to A first.

**Working Case:**

```
# Computer A Listens (IP 1.2.3.4)
netcat -ul 3000

# Computer B Initiates
netcat -u 1.2.3.4 3000
```

In the above case, the two "connect" via netcat, and I can send and receive data both ways. This leads me to believe this is not a port forwarding or routing issue.

**Broken Case:**

```
# Computer B Listens (IP 5.6.7.8)
netcat -ul 3000

# Computer A Initiates
netcat -u 5.6.7.8 3000
```

In this broken case, the two are not able to "connect" via netcat, and I can't send any data between either endpoints.

I've also tried using straight up packet sending tools to send UDP packets between A and B. Same thing happens, B is unable to receive anything from A until after B sends a packet to A.

I have no idea why something like this would happen, especially with UDP. Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

**EDIT**

Checked out port forwarding on B.  Here's the current iptables configuration:

```
$iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:3000 to:192.168.3.2:3000 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  0    --  anywhere             anywhere 



$iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     0    --  anywhere             anywhere                     
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.3.2         udp dpt:3000 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Am I missing something in my iptables configuration for proper forwarding of anywhere:3000 to 192.168.3.2:3000 for UDP?

Comment: This is typically behavior of a stateful firewall. UDP is a stateless protocol. So many firewalls will automatically open a port in the reverse direction after UDP traffic heading outbound. This means port forwarding is not configured correctly on firewall B.

Comment: And if you are dealing with different ISPs in A and B, it also very much depends on what the ISPs are filtering, if the do carrier grade NAT (then you need STUN), etc.

Comment: @Appleoddity you appear to be correct so far.  I just tested the same setup with a different port.  I added new forwarding rules on A, but not on B, and the behavior is the same.  So it appears that the original forwarding rules on B were not working like you said, and B's stateful firewall is allowing bidirectional comms once B initiates.  Will examine B's forwarding rules more carefully and come back.

Comment: Added a new edit above to include iptables configuration... is there something wrong with it?